# How to add google satellite as a base layer for a geoserver generated openlayers page

Tags: openlayers-2

İ have added a shapefile to geoserver and generate a WMS page. I want to add google satellite  as a base layer but i can't do it.

Any hint on how to add google satellite as a base layer?

Comment: IMO, it beats the purpose of building a solution using an opensource toolkit (openlayers) and then placing a cornerstone that is dependant on a  constantly changing proprietary tiling solution (googlemaps).  Why dont your look for GIBS and / or `http://maps.opengeo.org/geowebcache/service/wms`?

Answer (score 2):

You don't Add the Google layers in Geoserver. You call them in your OpenLayers Application.

This sample shows how you can call Google Layers in OpenLayers: [Google (v3) Layer Example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/google-v3.html)

So you will call Google Layers as the BaseMap, and add your [WMS](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wms.html) layer (from Geoserver) on top of the Base map.

To Clarify, the preview option in GeoServer is just for previewing. The OpenLayers that ships with Geoserver, is a light version, with a lot of classes missing. You will have to use the Full OpenLayers library, and create your own JavaScript App

Comment: Thanks Devdatta for your fast replay. my question is as we know Geoserver can genertae an openlayer code by default with many functionality. By keeping all the functionality, simply adding Google layer as a BaseMap. How can i do this?

Comment: That is just for previewing. The OpenLayers that ships with Geoserver, is a light version, with a lot of classes missing. You will have to use the Full OpenLayers library, and create your own JavaScript App.